# Set mergetool to only open certain extensions and use local files for others

Tags: git, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

I'm trying to merge two branches that have `.py` and `.png` files. Is there a way to set all the `.png` files to be local and only open with mergetool the `.py` files? I already did `git checkout --ours` / `--theirs` to choose the correct `.png` files to conserve but every time I open the mergetool these files keep popping up. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `git mergetool` command runs over the *unresolved* files by default, so the simplest thing is to mark the `.png` files as "correctly resolved" *first*.  See the note below, in the longer **DETAILS** section, for more about this.

That said, you can also supply pathnames to `git mergetool`, so you can list precisely those unresolved `.py` files.  That's just a small matter of shell scripting:

```
git ls-files --unmerged
```

produces the list of such files (with, alas, all the `--stage` data as well), which you can then filter using, e.g., `awk`:

```
git ls-files --unmerged | awk '$4 ~ /\.py$/ { print $4 } ' | uniq
```

(it's definitely possible to put the `uniq` into the `awk` code, but simpler just to *run* `uniq`).  Verify that this produces the right list of  files; it's then trivial to have the shell expand this into place:

```
git mergetool $(git ls-files --unmerged | awk '$4 ~ /\.py$/ { print $4 } ' | uniq)
```

## Details

When you run `git merge`—or indeed, any of the various commands that use Git's merge engine, including `git cherry-pick` for instance—and there is a conflict, Git leaves extra information in what Git calls the *index* or *staging area*.  These are two names for the same thing, and there's a third name, now largely obsolete, but it still shows up in flags: the *cache*, as in `git rm --cached` or `git diff --cached`.  (Some commands, including `git diff`, accept `--staged` as a synonym, but `git rm` still doesn't even as of Git 2.39.)

Normally—as in, when not in the middle of a merge conflict—Git's index aka staging area contains a *full copy* of every file in the form it will have if you run `git commit *right now*.<sup>1</sup>  But merging involves reading *three versions* of each file:

- the *merge base* version is the one each "side" started with;
- the `--ours` version is the one "we" had in "our" commit when we started our `git merge`; and
- the `--theirs` version is the one "they" had in "their" commit when we started our `git merge`.<sup>2</sup>

Git starts by looking at all three of these versions.  If all three *match*, there's no problem, and the merge result is any of the three versions.  If *two* match and *one* is different, there's again no problem.  The usual problem comes in when *all three are different*.  (There can also be some other problems, e.g., when both "sides" created a new but different file with the same name, but we'll ignore these cases for simplicity.)

When all three files *are* different, Git really does have to merge some work.  For plain-text files, Git does a line-by-line diff of the base version against each of the branch-tip versions.  This results in *two separate diffs*.  Git then tries to *combine* the two diffs, applying *both sets of changes* to the base version.

If all goes well—if Git believes it successfully combined "our changes" with "their changes", in other words—Git then treats the resulting merged file as the correct merged result, and writes that file to your working tree, so that you can see it, and to its own index, ready for committing.  **It's when things go less-well that you get a merge conflict.**

Again, remember that Git's index / staging-area normally holds *a copy of every file*.  So if Git is able to *merge* two sets of changes to, say, `README.txt`, Git will put the *merged version* of `README.txt` into both its index (ready to be committed) and your working tree (so that you can see what Git did).  The index copy is at what Git calls "stage zero".  But if the merge goes wrong, here's what Git does:

- Git puts the *base* version into the index in "staging slot 1" for this file name;
- Git puts the `--ours` version into the index in "slot 2" for this file name; and
- Git puts the `--theirs` version into the index in "slot 3" for this file name.

The result is that the index now has *three* files named, e.g., `README.txt` or `file.py` or `image.jpg`.

If the file is text and Git *attempted* a merge, Git puts its best attempt at merging, plus conflict markers, into your working tree, under the file's name (`README.txt` or whatever, again).  If the file is *not* text, such as `image.jpg`, Git leaves some version in your working tree.  Git doesn't put conflict markers in because binary files don't have "lines" in the first place.

**In all of these cases** it is your job to *resolve the conflicts*.  You do this by picking out the *right* merged result and stuffing that into Git's index at "slot zero", erasing the three conflicting versions.  For a file like `file.py`, you might open the working tree copy in your editor, for instance, and edit it and hand-resolve the conflict.  You can then write out the updated `file.py` and run:

```
git add file.py
```

This tells Git: *Erase the three nonzero-slot entries, and copy the working-tree version of `file.py` into the index at slot zero.*  The file is now "resolved".

Git allows the merge to complete—that is, you'll run `git merge --continue` or perhaps simply `git commit`—once *all* files in Git's index are back at "slot zero".  Until then, any file at any nonzero slot number is "unresolved".  In most cases, if there's a file in "slot 1", there's a file of the same name in "slot 2" and "slot 3" as well.  (The cases where this isn't true are ones we are not covering here.)

It's the `git add` command or—if you want to remove the file—a `git rm` command that *resolves* the file, by erasing the nonzero slots and writing the correct to-be-committed file to Git's index at slot zero.  Until you `git commit`, you can then *overwrite* the slot-zero file with another (also slot-zero) file, so you can do a first pass at resolving and `git add` and then test, if you like: there's no need to keep files unresolved.  But some people do like to keep them unresolved until the very end, so if you are one of those people, just remember how this works: whatever is in slot zero is what gets committed, and `git commit` won't let you commit until everything that's in Git's index is in there at slot zero.

**The point of the staging area is partly to allow these nonzero slots, and partly to allow you to change your mind about what files are in slot zero.**  You use `git add` to copy things into Git's index (at slot zero, always) and they're now ready-to-be-committed, but they just sit there, being ready, until you actually *run* `git commit`.  If you `git add` again, you *replace* some file(s) with newer versions; if you do this *before* you `git commit`, the versions you replaced never get committed.

With that in mind, we can now look at `git mergetool`, and also some special weirdness with `git checkout` and `git restore`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, what's in the index is actually a blob hash ID: the index holds pre-compressed, pre-de-duplicated "copies" of files, which take no space if they're literally the same as any existing committed file.  But you can just think of them as actual copies of files: except for using no disk space, they *behave like* copies of files.

<sup>2</sup>Note that for `git cherry-pick`, the ours and theirs names still make sense.  The merge base version is the parent of the "theirs" commit.  Since `git rebase` works by repeated cherry-picking, this also makes sense, *except* that `git rebase` starts by *checking out* "their" branch-tip commit.  It then uses `git cherry-pick` on each of "our" commits.  This causes the ours and theirs relationships to change.  That's a matter for a separate discussion, though.

---

#### Mergetool works by reading the index

You run `git mergetool` *after* you run `git merge` and get merge conflicts.  What `git mergetool` does is look for those nonzero-staging-slot entries *in* Git's index.  Files with a nonzero staging number are *unresolved*.

If you run `git mergetool` and resolve some files, and/or use `git add` to resolve some files, and then interrupt the `git mergetool` run and start *another* `git mergetool` run, Git starts over, listing the unmerged files.  If that list of files is now *smaller*, those are the only ones still unmerged.

Hence, if you have some `*.jpg` files that you can resolve, you can do that first:

```
git checkout --ours foo.jpg
git checkout --theirs bar.jpg
git add foo.jpg bar.jpg         # these two files are now resolved
```

Running `git mergetool` at this point will not attempt to merge `bar.jpg` and `foo.jpg` because they're not unresolved any more.

When `git mergetool` brings up your actual merge tool (whatever that may be), you're supposed to resolve the conflicts *in* that merge tool, and then exit the merge tool to tell `git mergetool` that it is done.  The `git mergetool` command will then run `git add` *for you* on that file.<sup>3</sup>  That's how `git mergetool` can later pick up where you left off, after you interrupt it.

This brings us to some oddities with `git checkout`, some of which are cleaned up in `git restore`.  The checkout and restore commands have flags:

- `--ours` means *get the file from slot 2*.
- `--theirs` means *get the file from slot 3*.
- There's one missing here: there should probably be a `--base` to mean *slot 1*, but it's just not there.

These options tell `git checkout` and `git restore` to read the index copy from the given slot, and write that out to the working tree copy of that file.  These options *don't* do anything *to* the index itself, so the file remains unresolved.

You can, however, *also* run `git checkout commit -- path`.  *This* option tells `git checkout` to reach into the specified *`commit`* and fine the *committed* copy of the specified *`path`*, and `git checkout` does this by *writing the file to slot zero of the index* first.  This action erases slots 1, 2, and 3.  So *this* kind of `git checkout` marks the file resolved!

With `git restore`, you can do the same thing, but the places that `git restore` writes to are specified by the `--worktree` (or `-W`) and `--staged` (or `-S`) flags.  So:

```
git restore -SW -s HEAD -- path/to/file
```

tells `git restore` to extract our (`HEAD`) version of the file *and* write that to *both* the index (`-S`) and your working tree (`-W`).  So this too resolves the file, like `git checkout HEAD -- path/to/file` would.  Leaving out the `-S` means that `git restore` *won't* mark the file resolved.

You might wonder why this is all so complicated.  The answer is in part "because Git just grew over time", i.e., this wasn't actually *planned*, it just happened by mistake.  It's also in part "because Git commands try to be flexible tools": `git restore` in particular is more flexible than `git checkout` as it can write, separately, to Git's index *or* your working tree *or both*.  The old, more-confusing `git checkout` command writes to Git's index if extracting from a commit, and always writes to your working tree.

Last, if you want to "un-mark" a file as resolved—i.e., to return it to its unresolved state, both `git checkout` and `git restore` have an option `-m` for doing this.  Note that it destroys any working tree work you've done, and `-m` means something different to `git checkout` if you're *not* in "merge mode" (which to me is yet another reason to avoid the old `git checkout` command, using `git switch` and `git restore` instead).  Again, I won't cover any of the details here, as this is already long enough.

---

<sup>3</sup>Precisely when and whether `git mergetool` runs this `git add` is a little tricky because Git doesn't really know whether your merge tool has done the merge.  There are several knobs you can configure to tell `git mergetool` how to interpret results from the merge tool.  But if you're using a *known* merge tool, that's already configured correctly, this is all invisible.  It's when you want to use your own merge tool that you have to know how to configure this.  We won't cover these details here.